# Angularjs pagination data doesn't refresh when links clicked

Tags: angularjs, http, pagination

I have a pagination factory, which I didn't write, i'm just using, it gets passed the $scope and a string, the string representing the http action.
 It works with `GET` requests however I am now trying to implement it on a `POST` request and for some reason it is not working. The pagination bar is loaded, with the right amount of buttons. e.g I have 1 thousand records it loads 100 buttons 10 records per page but when clicking the buttons the data is static, it doesn't update.

Pagination factory:

```
angular.module('customers')
       .factory('PaginationFactory', PaginationFactory);

function PaginationFactory($scope, action) {

    $scope.filteredPages = [];
    $scope.currentPage = 1;
    $scope.numPerPage = 10;
    $scope.maxSize = 15;

    $scope.makePages = function () {
         $scope.search_customers = [];

         angular.forEach($scope.get_list, function (item) {
             //Push the items into the list...
             if (callerAction == 'search_customers') {
                 $scope.search_customers.push(item);
              }
    });
};

$scope.$watch('currentPage + numPerPage', function () {

    var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage)
    end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;

    if (callerAction == 'search_customers') {
        var pages = $scope.filteredPages = $scope.search_customers.slice(begin, end);
    return pages;
});
$scope.makePages();
}
```

HTML:

```
 <ul uib-pagination
     total-items="search_customers.length"
     ng-model="currentPage"
     max-size="maxSize"
     boundary-link-numbers="true"
     rotate="false">
 </ul>
```

Post request:

```
 $scope.searchCustomers = function() {
    $scope.status = $scope.selected.charAt(0);
    $http.post(API_URL+"v1/customers/search", $scope.searchData)
        .then(function (response){
            var action = 'search_customers';
            $scope.get_list = response.data;
           console.log($scope)
            new PaginationFactory($scope, action);
        }, function (response) {
            console.log("no data");
        });
```

If anybody could help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are you injecting your factory to the controller?